# How to count int input using python

Tags: python, string, count, binary, integer

so i have func that convert bytes to binary and i want to count how many amount binary.

> example `b'\xd8\xe9\xbdR'` binary is **11011000 11101001 10111101 01010010**

> if it is count **how many amount**, it will be count **4.**

i already tried using split, but it says only can be used in string. so can someone help me to fix it?

here's my code to convert bytes to binary:

```
def biner(password):
    print(password)
    password[0]
    for my_byte in password:
        if my_byte != None:
            return ' '.join(f'{my_byte:0>8b}' for my_byte in password)
```

here's the web i tried to [count](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Did you mean `len(password)`?

Comment: how many binary that was, not the len from password @quamrana

Comment: But they are the same thing. Why would they be different?

Comment: @HelpMe Aren't you counting how many 8-bit binary blocks there are? len(password) works. but if there is some magic string changing you are doing behind the scenes you already have your solution as you 'split' into the groups you are counting no? A counter or simply string.split works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So quite simply you can take advantage of your script that already splits your input into your desired separation. So using string.split works just fine here.

```
def biner(password):
    print(password)
    password[0]
    for my_byte in password:
        if my_byte != None: #probably better to replace with is not None rather than != None
            string_output = ' '.join(f'{my_byte:0>8b}' for my_byte in password)
            return string_output, len(string_output.split(' '))#so here we get your 'count' simply the number of splits defined in string_output
```

Comment: There are no such errors with the code in this answer.